# Passing attributes between components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

NewBee Lightning, I have a very small requirement of passing values from textbox of  firstname field from one component to other component and last name field value from second component to first component. Below is my code for component one

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">


<link href='/resource/bootstrap/' rel="stylesheet"/>
<body aura:id="content">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">DashBoard</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ui:inputText aura:id="fname" label="First Name" required="true"/>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="lname" label="Last Name" required="true"/>

</body>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: A little note about your code, tags starting with ui: are deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using event handling for same. There are 2 options -

1. either use application event
2. component event

You can read more about it at - 
[Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component.htm)
[Application events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm)